# Extract zip without creating new folder

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Currently If I upload a zip with (myfolder.zip) then it extract and create a folder myfolder/image1.jpeg  I need it should extract the content on root like image1/jpeg .

```
function uploadzip($args){

        $message['flag'] = false;
        $message['message'] = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
        if($args["data"]["name"]) { 
            $filename = $args["data"]["name"];
            $source = $args["data"]["tmp_name"];
            $type = $args["data"]["type"];

            $name = explode(".", $filename);
            $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
            foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
                if($mime_type == $type) {
                    $okay = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }

            $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
            if(!$continue) {
                $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
            }

            $target_path = $args["path"].$filename;   // change this to the correct site path

            if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                $x = $zip->open($target_path);
                if ($x === true) {
                    $zip->extractTo($args["path"]); // change this to the correct site path

                    $zip->close();

                    unlink($target_path);
                }
                $message['message'] = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
                $message['flag'] =true;
            }

            return $message;
        } 
    }
```

$args['data'] = $this->request->data['Uploadzip']['zip_file'];
$args['path'] = WWW_ROOT.'upload/';

When I upload a zip file named abcd.zip it gets uploaded and then gets extracted in upload folder like this upload/abcd/image1.jpeg I need it should not have abcd upload/image1.jpeg

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: Currently the above code works but it create a new folder, I just want to unzip without creating any directory.

Comment: So what's the value of `$args["path"]` and where do you want to put the files that you extract?

Comment: $args['data'] = $this->request->data['Uploadzip']['zip_file'];

$args['path'] = WWW_ROOT.'upload/';

let me explain when I upload a zip file named abcd.zip it gets uploaded and then gets extracted in upload folder like this 
upload/abcd/image1.jpeg
I need it should not have abcd
upload/image1.jpeg

Comment: Read the user contributed note by php-dev at proneticas dot net on the [php docs page for extractTo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
function uploadzip($args){

        $message['flag'] = false;
        $message['message'] = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
        if($args["data"]["name"]) { 
            $filename = $args["data"]["name"];
            $source = $args["data"]["tmp_name"];
            $type = $args["data"]["type"];

            $name = explode(".", $filename);
            $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
            foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
                if($mime_type == $type) {
                    $okay = true;
                    break;
                } 
            }

            $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
            if(!$continue) {
                $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
            }

            $target_path = $filename;   // change this to the correct site path

            if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                $x = $zip->open($target_path);
                if ($x === true) {
                    $zip->extractTo($args["path"]); // change this to the correct site path

                    $zip->close();

                    unlink($target_path);
                }
                $message['message'] = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
                $message['flag'] =true;
            }

            return $message;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I tried this, but still same it still creates directory and then extract there, I want it should extract directly without creating folder

Comment: what is the value of $args["path"] ?

Comment: $args["path"] = /app/webroot/upload/

Comment: remplace this  ligne "$target_path = $args["path"].$filename;" with this   $target_path = $args["path"].$name[0].'.'$name[1]; and tell me the result

Comment: #ahmed Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$name' (T_VARIABLE) in

Comment: what's the data of var_dump($name); ??

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "greenbazar" [1]=> string(3) "zip" }

Comment: Sorry i forgot the  point , remplace with this ligne $target_path = $args["path"].$name[0].'.'.$name[1];